# Genymotion not detecting Virtualbox on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox

I have installed both Genymotion as well as VirtualBox on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I can access the VirtualBox from dash and run it.
During the installation of Genymotion (after executing the `.bin` file) the terminal message also indicated the presence of a valid VirtualBox, I got the following output on terminal during installation:

```
- Trying to find VirtualBox toolset .................... OK (Valid version of VirtualBox found: 5.1.28r117968)
- Extracting files ..................................... OK (Extract into: [/opt/genymobile/genymotion])
- Installing launcher icon ............................. OK

Installation done successfully.

You can now use these tools from [/opt/genymobile/genymotion]:
 - genymotion
 - genymotion-shell
 - gmtool
```

But when I launch Genymotion from the dash it always gives the following error:

```
In order to work, Genymotion requires VirtualBox to be installed on your computer. You can download the latest version of VirtualBox from www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads.

Genymotion log archive has been saved in /home/sourabh/genymotion-log.zip
Please contact Genymotion support for more help.
```

I have already tried other solutions posted on this site, for instance running

```
sudo /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup
```

but nothing works for me. What has possibly gone wrong?

Comment: If you have Secure Boot enabled you may have to disable it because it prevents Virtualbox "drivers" from loading.

Comment: What version of virtualbox and how did you install it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

load all virtualbox kernal modules. worked for me.
`modprobe vboxdrv vboxnetflt vboxpci vboxnetad`

Below is a screenshot about genymotion working after loading all kernel modules:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I fixed this a long back using the same technique. Thanks anyway.